# Trying to calculate share - summarize function not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the share of a certain variable cost for each country, related to the total. However, when I try to create the "share" column through mutate, it yields all answers as 1.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
db %>% 
  group_by(country,group) %>% 
  summarize(cost=sum(cost)) %>%
  mutate(share=cost/sum(cost))
```

This is the table it is generating:

```
# Groups:   cluster [18]
   cluster group          cost share
   <chr>   <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AT      A              7810.     1
 2 AU      C              7786.     1
 3 CA      C              5920.     1
 4 KO      B            172702.     1
 5 DE      A             40894.     1
 6 ES      A             26357.     1
 7 FR      A             65735.     1
 8 GB      C             11240.     1
 9 IT      A             85045.     1
10 JP      B             10069.     1
```

I've tried inverting the positions of group and country on the group_by(), but the share column  is still returning the shares as a % of the group, instead of the total sum. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Nothing changed. Must be something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the default behavior of `summarise` is to output a grouped dataframe when grouping by more than one variable (it drops one variable and keeps the next).
To solve it you can add an `ungroup`:

```
db %>% 
  group_by(country,group) %>% 
  summarize(cost=sum(cost)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(share=cost/sum(cost))
```

Or from dplyr version > 1.0.0:

```
db %>% 
  group_by(country,group) %>% 
  summarize(cost=sum(cost), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(share=cost/sum(cost))
```